# Remove specific numbers from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to remove specific numbers from each array, but no success. I have googled it, but I nothing found similar. First I created an array by commas, and then I wanted to remove `021` and dash from `array[i]` (each value), just the first three characters.

```js
$('.numbers').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().indexOf(',') != -1) {
    var seprate = $(this).text();
    var array = seprate.split(',');
    $.each(array, function(i, el) {

      if (array[i].indexOf("021") != -1) {
      array[i].substr(0,2).replace("021", "")
      }

      $('.phonearray').append(array[i]);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.phonearray {
background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="numbers">
  02188776021 , 09123074859 , 021-45676543 , 021 -55446021
</div>

<div class="phonearray">

</div>
```

And I used `substr` to remove the first three characters, but it not working.

Comment: `.replace()` doesn't modify the original string, you have to assign the result to something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace()` doesn't modify the original string (JavaScript strings are immutable). You need to assign the result back to the array.

You can do what you want with a regular expression replacement. The regexp `^021\s*-?` matches `021` at the beginning, possibly followed by whitespace and a `-` character.

I also used `.trim()` to remove the spaces around the comma.

```js
$('.numbers').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().indexOf(',') != -1) {
    var seprate = $(this).text();
    var array = seprate.split(',');
    $.each(array, function(i, el) {
      var val = el.trim().replace(/^021\s*-?/, '');
      $('.phonearray').append(val);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.phonearray {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="numbers">
  02188776021 , 09123074859 , 021-45676543 , 021 -55446021
</div>

<div class="phonearray">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's define the problem first:
You have a string that contains phone numbers separated by commas, and you have to remove the prefix if found in each number

First thought:

```
function removePrefixes(input /* string */) {
  return input.split(',')
   .map(x => x.trim())
   .map(x => x.replace(/\b021\s*/, ''))
   .join(', ')
}
```

Replace the original text:

```
$('.numbers').text((i, text) => removePrefixes(text));
```

Examples:

```
removePrefixes("02188776021 , 09123074859 , 021-45676543 , 021 -55446021") 
// returns "88776021, 09123074859, -45676543, -55446021"
```

**Explanation:**

1. split by commas, converted to an array
2. remove the surrounding spaces (trim)
3. replace the numbers starting by 021, the `\b` means word boundary, `\s*` any spaces after it
4. join the collection, back to string

From here do whatever you want.